# How to check whether mobile date is current

Tags: java, android, calendar

I am taking the Current date by using the following sets of lines.

```
java.util.Calendar calc = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();

int day = calc.get(java.util.Calendar.DATE);
int month = calc.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH)+1;
int year = calc.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR);
```

I am getting date but what  if Mobile date is not of the current date. I am matching my mobile date with server date Their date is current and mobile date is not current.

Is their any validation if mobile date is not current then show notification.

Comment: You have to compare it, if not equal then you can redirect user to setting screen...

Comment: Thanks For Your reply!! But Can you please tell me with which date should I comparer. By using above function I will get mobiles date. Is their any function by which I will current date so that I will compare that date with mobile date.

Comment: You only told i will check it with server date. so you came to know whether mobile date is current or not, then you can show notification to user. Is anything else you require ?

Comment: Thanks Yugandhar  I will check my mobile date with the server date then Only I will pass the user to enter in the application. But is their any alternative by using I will can tackle with this problem. Means with out hitting the server. What I have to do I have download some files from the server depending upon the link that I am passing if date is not current then download will not happen. That's why I have to check current date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL http://timeanddate.com gives current date and time for your current location.

If you can send HTTP request to this server you will get html or xml file. If you decode that file with parsers available in android you will get current date.

I didn't tried, but definitely possible. Try if you are interested.

Comment: Great!!  Excellent!! I will Implemented.

Comment: OK I will remember this next time onwards. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can just notify user to change time and date. I don't think you can set time and date programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html
will give you system date. check with selected date.